ArcGIS.Core.CalledOnWrongThreadException: 'This method or property must be called on the thread this object was created on this.Dispatcher.Invoke
Even after calling this.Dispatcher.Invoke ,we are still getting error ArcGIS.Core.CalledOnWrongThreadException while adding items to treeview on line tvSections.Items.Add(featuremasfoot.GetObjectID().ToString())
Full function code is as below .Here Analyze method is called in  QueuedTask.Run from another method
 private void Analyze(FeatureClass source_layer, FeatureLayer target_layer)
 {
     var objParcel = target_layer.GetSpatialReference(); 
         using (Table table = source_layer)
         {
             var reafilter = new SpatialQueryFilter()
             {
                 FilterGeometry = null,
                 SubFields = "*",
                 WhereClause = 123
             };

             using (RowCursor reaCursor = table.Search(reafilter))
             {
                 using (Table table1 = target_layer.GetTable())
                 {
                     while (reaCursor.MoveNext())
                     {
                         Feature featurerea = reaCursor.Current as Feature;
                         ArcGIS.Core.Geometry.Geometry shape = featurerea.GetShape();
                         ArcGIS.Core.Geometry.Geometry shape2 = GeometryEngine.Instance.Project(shape, objParcel);
                         ArcGIS.Core.Geometry.Geometry shape3 = GeometryEngine.Instance.Buffer(shape2, -2);

                         var parcelpolyfilter = new SpatialQueryFilter()
                         {
                             FilterGeometry = shape3,
                             SpatialRelationship = SpatialRelationship.Intersects,
                             SubFields = "*"
                         };

                         using (RowCursor parcelpolyCursor = table1.Search(parcelpolyfilter))
                         {
                         // Use Dispatcher to update UI elements on the UI thread
                         this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                         {
                                 tvSections.Items.Add(featurerea.GetObjectID().ToString());

                                 while (parcelpolyCursor.MoveNext())
                                 {
                                 }
                             }));
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    
 }


This looks like a CoreHost application to me, however QueuedTask is used for aynchronous operations on the worker-thread in AddIns. Check out QueuedWorker for asynchronous operations on Core-Objects.

@kai I fixed issue and posted answer

I fixed this in a way like all the operation related to List are done in background thread and once everything finished ,assigning  data to List view is done in UI thread by invoking as below
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{

    List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();

    foreach (var pcid in parcelIds)
    {
        var item = new MyItem { Name = pcid };

        // Add the new item to the list
        items.Add(item);
    }
    lsview.ItemsSource = items;
});

